# How to remove disclose indicator button from left side and always show delete button on right side in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview

I create a UITableView and show it on Edit mode, In edit mode a (-) sign was showing on left side of each row, when pressing this button a Delete button come's from the right side and by pressing this delete button the row was deleted.

I want to remove (-) button from left side and I want to show delete button always on the right side.

**In short I want a delete button on right side which delete my row just like we delete row in edit mode. But do not want the (-) button on left side.**

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,this can only be achieved through a custom `UITableViewCell` and it is also easy.
[Here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) is a link from the cocoa with love site and
[Here](http://icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/) is one from icodeblog

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but both link's do not delete the cell, only create a customize cell and do not solve my problem. Any other idea.

Comment: You can create the custom cell with a button with an action to delete the cell,initially hide the button by setting its alpha to zero and in edit mode show it.

Comment: I don't want to hide delete button but i want that the cell was deleted as it was delete in edit mode with animation.